# no option to add Client side library Visual studio 2022 on mac m1

Tags: c#, frontend, libman, visual-studio-mac-2022

I want to add bootstrap to my project and
didn't found Client-side library on options

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CnC7.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Library Manager feature (Add Client-side Library) is not supported on VS Mac.  You can request it, and if it gets enough votes the team might consider it a priority to port to Mac.

There is also an older port (i.e. not the latest, not officially supported, may have bugs/issues) of it [here](https://github.com/mrward/LibraryManager) ([blog post](https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2019/07/13/LibManSupportInVisualStudioMac8-1/) by the fork author from 2019).

Comment: I solved this problem by copy www-root thanks Jimmy